# Using transaction to check if multiple docs exists, add them if not

Tags: javascript, firebase, transactions, google-cloud-firestore

This is my situation: I have a local json file with a lot of entries. This file is not sanitized (i.e. there might be repeated entries in the list). My goal is to add each item (once) from the local file to my DB using firestore.

The docs say that a transaction can be multiple `get` operations followed by multiple `update/set/delete` operations.However, the samples usually only have a single `get`. How can I go and have multiple get operations without nesting inside `then()`? I guess I could get the entire collection and compare the result. But then I won't have learned how to use multiple `get`!

Sample data:

```
/* mock data */
var myList = [
    {
        id: '123',
        name: 'Aloha 1',
        latitude: 0.0,
        longitude: 1.1,
        url: 'https://www.google.com'
    },
    {
        id: '321',
        name: 'Aloha 2',
        latitude: 3.0,
        longitude: 3.1,
        url: 'https://www.gmail.com'
    },
    {
        id: '123',
        name: 'Aloha 1',
        latitude: 0.0,
        longitude: 1.1,
        url: 'https://www.google.com'
    },
    {
        id: '321',
        name: 'Aloha 2',
        latitude: 3.0,
        longitude: 3.1,
        url: 'https://www.gmail.com'
    }
];
```

This is my attempt (I know this is wrong, I have a sequence of `get`/`set` operations...):

```
var transaction = db.runTransaction(t => {
    for (item in myList) {
        const ref = db.collection('superList').doc(item.id);
        const sanitizedEntry = {
            name: item.name,
            location: new admin.firestore.GeoPoint(item.lat, item.lon),
            url: item.url,
        }
        t.get(ref).then(doc => {
            if (!doc.exists) {
                t.set(ref, sanitizedEntry);
            }
        });
    }
})
.then(result => {
    console.log('Transaction success!');
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log('Transaction failure:', err);
});
```

The resulting DB should only contain `superList/123`, and `superList/321` (plus whatever other documents are already in the collection).

Comment: I'm not sure why you need a transaction here.  You can just try to get the doc, then set it if get() doesn't return anything.  You only need a transaction if there are multiple changes that need to be made all at the same instant, or not at all.

Comment: Isn't a transaction more efficient? `myList` can be quite large. Btw, this might be unrelated, but the pricing when using transaction/batch, is it per operation or per transaction/batch?

Comment: I would say that a transaction is going to be a lot less efficient overall, because it has to keep track of everything you've done and ensure that the whole sequence can be played without any competing changes.  I don't think transactions change anything in terms of billing.

Comment: Thanks. It worked fine! However, I still don't know how to aggregate multiple `get()` in a transaction. I know I can get a single doc or an entire collection, but what would I do if I wanted multiple, not all, docs from a collection (in a transaction)? I still can't find an example of "[...] any number of `get()` operations followed by any number of write operations [...]".

Comment: I think you just to t.get() as much as needed. Are you thinking it's more complicated than that?

Comment: I feel like it is! But I guess that's a discussion for another place. Your comments already helped me solved my question!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fixed number of items to check, you can use getAll to get many documents concurrently.  This is an all or nothing result.  You'll either get all documents or an error.

```
let superList = db.collection('superList');
let myRef0 = superList.doc(item[0].id);
let myRef1 = superList.doc(item[1].id);
let myRef2 = superList.doc(item[2].id);
let myRef3 = superList.doc(item[3].id);

return db.getAll(itemRef0, itemRef1, itemRef2, itemRef3).then(response => {
  // The data is returned in an array, here
}.catch(err => {
  console.error(`An error happened ${err}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As per suggestion, not using transactions worked fine (edit: fixed code):

```
for (item in myList) {
     const itemRef = db.collection('superList').doc(item.id);
     const itemDoc = itemRef.get()
                .then(itemSnap => {
                    if (!itemSnap.exists) {
                        const itemObj = {
                            name: gymitemRaw.name,
                            location: new admin.firestore.GeoPoint(item.llatitude, item.longitude),
                            url: item.url,
                        };
                        itemRef.set(itemObj);
                    }else{
                        console.log('Item already exists in DB');
                    }
                });
}
```